# Form submit via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my code:

```
 document.imgUploadForm.submit();
```

or

```
$.ajax({ url: "Controler/MyMethod",
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: { data: $('#imgUploadForm').serialize() },
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            }
       })
```

but in my action method, the values from the form aren't submitted. Why?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code?

Comment: Hey!!! You just edited your question! where is the previous question????

Comment: @gdoron What would my method have as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax request should be like this

```
$.ajax({ url: "MyController/MyMethod",
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data:$('#imgUploadForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        }
   })
```

Comment: And what would MyMethod has as parameter?

Comment: All the names you assigned in form elements will be accessible via post or request.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
data: { data: $('#imgUploadForm').serialize() },
```

To this:

```
data: $('#imgUploadForm').serialize(),
```

Full code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "controllerName")',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#imgUploadForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        }
   });
```

Comment: @PetkoXyz. You shouldn't! you should have ask a new question if you had to. don't edit questions to a new one. What about the answers?!